# PHP variables and XML elements

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to use PHP variables to load certain elements from a XML file, so if index.php?id=1 is loaded it would pull the information from $projects->project[1]. No errors come up in the following code, but nothing gets displayed. Any help is appreciated :)

```
<?php
$projects = simplexml_load_file('portfolio.xml');
$id = $_GET["id"];
echo $projects->project[$id]->title;
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($projects)` to ensure it contains data after loading? Also, try with `error_reporting(~0)`

Comment: A little example of the xml file will help a lot!, also remember that node count starts at 0, so if you have one and only one node you will not get anything. Also, as a good practice you should enable error reporting with the highest value possible (i.e error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors',true);)

Comment: Post your XML sample data, it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It may be one of two things (or both):

1. echo doesn't show anything if there is nothing to show.
2. there has been an error, but your server is not reporting it, try checking logs if there are any. Also check if error reporting is enabled.

That said, try using print_r or var_dump to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

print_r($_GET); die;
to check if u  are getting the data in get or not .

Comment: comes back with
Array ( [id] => 2 )

Comment: Means there no problem with your get request 
You should 
$projects = simplexml_load_file('portfolio.xml');
print_r($projects); 
and see whether $project object  contains $projects->project or not .

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(~0); // show me everything i do wrong

$projects = simplexml_load_file('portfolio.xml');

var_dump($projects); // make sure $projects actually has something

var_dump($_GET['id']); // are you getting the request data?

$id = (int) $_GET["id"]; // cast to int for good measure
                         // i'm assuming it's numeric, don't if its not

echo $projects->project[$id]->title; // still not showing anything?

var_dump($projects->project[$id]->title); // dump it for good measure
```